# print line that start with fatal in a text file using java

Tags: java, regex

i have a file. i have to extract those line whose starts with fatal like this one

**fatal: [infra2_aodh_container-4cc917f6]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "module_stderr": "nsenter: cannot open /proc/ns/mnt: No such file or directory\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", "rc": 1}**

Comment: Can you share some code? This probably has nothing to do with regex. Your trying to read a directory?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You don't realy need regular expressions for this.

You can just split the lines and  iterate through the lines and choose the ones that start with fatal (using the startsWith(String s) method.

Here's a solution using some Java 8 Streams:

```
public void Example() {
    String text = "fatal: something went wrong\nerror: something else went wrong\nFATAL: ...\nanother text\nand some more lines...";
    List<String> lines = Arrays.asList(text.split("\n"));

    String searched = "fatal";
    List<String> fatalMessages = lines.stream().filter(s -> s.toLowerCase().startsWith(searched)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    fatalMessages.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Output:

fatal: something went wrong

FATAL: ...

If you don't want the second line (with capital letters) just remove the 'toLowerCase()'.

Comment: actually file is having fatal in those line that i want to print so i just used if (line.contains("fatal:") )  {

Comment: so i got what i wanted but i need to split that string (above mentioned ) so that i am able to get  {"changed": false, "failed": true, "module_stderr": "nsenter: cannot open /proc/ns/mnt: No such file or directory\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", "rc": 1} this string ......can u help me

Comment: I'm not quite shure what you're asking for...
Could you explain it somehow different?